# What is in common between decimals and reminder

Tags: divisibility, project-euler

I am trying to understand [this solution for a Project Euler 26 problem](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-26-find-the-value-of-d-1000-for-which-1d-contains-the-longest-recurring-cycle/). Could you please explain what do the decimals and remainders have in common? In context of this solution.

Comment: The key take-away that I think you are looking for:  
"One more thing to note is that the maximum recurring cycle length of 1/d is d-1, as it is pretty obvious from the example. We can get d-1 different possible remainders from the number, since if the result is equal to or greater than d, then it is not a remainder."  

This drastically reduces the algorithmic runtime if we start with large d, since when d becomes less than the longest current recurring cycle, we need not search further.

Comment: @Orangutango, yep, but how do the recurring cycle of decimals relates to the recurring cycle of reminders ? Why are they equal ?

Comment: @AndreiPodoprîgora The relation is given by the long division algorithm: if you compute $1/n$ then the remainders pop up in this algorithm. Either a remainder becomes $0$ at some point, in which case the algorithm halts (like with $1/5 = 0.2$) or at some point the remainders repeat themselves in wich case the algorithm runs forever (like with $1/3 = 0.3333\dots$).